# How use Trans in i18n with JSON key which contains tags

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am have an JSON file for translations for few languages which looks like:

```
'RESPONSIBLE': "<b>Responsible</b> is {{name}}"
```

Inside the component I try different ways to use Trans tag like:

```
<Trans i18nKey="RESPONSIBLE" name={'Jon'}></Trans>
// or
<Trans>{t('RESPONSIBLE', {name: 'Jon'})}</Trans>
```

The best result was: **Responsible** is Jon. But still tags inside DOM just like part of string.

Also, I have the same situation with json like this:

```
 "NO_ACTIVE": "Please go to the <a class=\"no-wrap\" href=\"{{link}}\">Go Here</a>"
```

I can not properly use Trans for keys like this. When I try examples from documentations it works, but there tags is inside Trans tag, but in my case they inside json key

How can I properly use Trans tag in this cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs about [`<Trans>`](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component) are a bit confusing because there are different ways to use it. A solution in your case is to do [like this](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#alternative-usage-which-lists-the-components-v11.6.0):

```
<Trans
  i18nKey="RESPONSIBLE"
  values={{ name: "Jon" }}
  components={{ bold: <strong /> }}
/>
```

And in your translations:

```
'RESPONSIBLE': "<strong>Responsible</strong> is {{name}}"
```

By default [only some tags seem to be recognized](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#usage-with-simple-html-elements-like-less-than-br-greater-than-and-others-v10.4.0), so if you want to use `<b>` for `bold`, you can specify the tag `b` in the `components` prop as you pointed out in the comments:

```
<Trans
  i18nKey="RESPONSIBLE"
  values={{ name: "Jon" }}
  components={{ b: <b/> }}
/>
```

Comment: still the same, have <b>Responsible</b> is Jon

Comment: @Volodumr Alright, I think it's because the tag `<b>` is not allowed by default, I will edit my answer.

Comment: If change b to strong in json it works...

Comment: if in component say   components={{ b: <b /> }} it will work, without transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor changes) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Volodumr Nice, I didn't know we could also do that. Do you want me to update my answer to include this solution as well?

Comment: yes, you can and then I will accept is as right)